# What to do about 6 year old laptop

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, laptop, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS M1210 with a Nvidia 7400GO and 3GB of RAM. I would like to run Ubuntu again but I have found it to be sluggish and slow with Unity, Even the Gnome Fallback seems sluggish. I don't know if it is simple as a drive problem or if it is 13.04. I remember that everything seemed fine with 12.04.

Should I go back to the LTS of Ubuntu or should I stick it out? Can anyone recommend a less resource intensive desktop environment?

Answer (score 3):

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) uses the XFCE desktop, which is much less resource intensive. Everything else about the distro is pretty straightforward Ubuntu; packages are part of the regular Ubuntu release, so nearly every howto applies

If you want a more minimalistic desktop and still stay within the Ubuntu distros, try [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) which uses LXDE. This is even slimmer than XFCE, but also much more "stripped down" than the other desktops.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop, albeit slightly less powerful - 2gb ram, Intel graphics, etc - and just underwent that *exact* exercise.

Long story short, I ended up throwing a SSD in it and replaced the dead optical drive with the original HD, and it now *flies* - I'll double my RAM now and put off buying an Air for a little bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 is my recomendation for you!